# How to fix cronjob does not run execution bash on vestacp

Tags: cron, rclone

I have a bash file to copy files to google drive using rclone in /bin/bash :
`/home/ftpbackup/web/dbbackup/database_gdrive/rclone_db.sh>/dev/null 2> & 1`

I execute with the terminal running well. When executed with vestacp cronjob does not run.

The following is the contents of the bash file for rclone:

```
/usr/bin/ rclone copy backupdb.sql.gz remotegdrive:/backup_database/
```

Please help what is a mistake so that cronjob does not work. Please help immediately.

code of cronjob :

```
/bin/bash /home/ftpbackup/web/dbbackup/database_gdrive/rclone_db.sh>/dev/null 2> & 1
```

code of bash:

```
/usr/bin/ rclone copy backupdb.sql.gz remotegdrive:/backup_database/
```

Comment: Make sure you have execute permission for /home/ftpbackup/web/dbbackup/database_gdrive/rclone_db.sh

If no, perform the below command:
_"chmod +x /home/ftpbackup/web/dbbackup/database_gdrive/rclone_db.sh"_

Comment: @HarijithR I have done it and the rclone process works fine when I execute it with the terminal. When executed with cronjob it still fails. Please help

Comment: Can you please give the output of the below command?
_ls -al /home/ftpbackup/web/dbbackup/database_gdrive/rclone_db.sh_

Comment: This is output :
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ftpbackup ftpbackup 89 Jun 12 16:43 rclone_db.sh

I give chmod 777, and chmod +x